# Exchange 2010, Mutliple IP's

Tags: exchange, routing

I have multiple IP's on our new exchange 2010 box, but I need it to only send on IP #1. It appears to just route them randomly, I'm wondering how I go about telling exchange that I want it to route on only ONE ip address.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the "Set-SendConnector" cmdlet. Execute the command below from an Exchange Management Shell:

```
Set-SendConnector -Identity "Send Connector Name" -SourceIPAddress x.x.x.x
```

By default, the SourceIPAddress is set to 0.0.0.0, which corresponds to all IP addreses on the machine. Scoping it down to a single IP address will get you what you want.

Comment: @Evan: Is this available anywhere in the EMC? Thanks.

Comment: @joeqwerty: Not that I'm aware of. I don't have an Exchange 2010 handy to look at right now, but it's definitely not exposed in 2007. (Frankly, that pisses me off, too. I'm a hardcore command-line kind of guy, but GUI management in Exchange 2007+ took a major step backward. I also rather dislike the whole mentality of Powershell. It's *NOT* at all Unix-like, and doesn't appeal to my Unix sysadmin background. Unix machines have config files in /etc, whereas Powershell has idiotic "cmd-lets" with hundreds of command-line arguments...  >sigh<)

Comment: @joeqwerty I found a checkbox for "Scoped Connector" in the send connector prop's, but I couldn't find a place to explicitly set the IP address.

Comment: @WedTM: Yeah-- a "Scoped Connector" is a different thing.

Comment: Right, the Scoped Connector option is for scoping the send connector to a particular server, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @joeqwerty: Close. A Scoped Send Connector can be used only by Hub Transport servers in the same Active Directory site-- not just a particular server. The classic example is two AD sites (corresponding to physical locations) that each have Internet connectivity, and a connection between. You want the Exchange Server computers in each site to deliver directly to the Internet, and to deliver intra-org messages directly to the other site. You can create a scoped send connector in each site for the SMTP address space "*" and it will be usable only by hub transports within that site.